# My Wordpress website shows nothing after some time

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I just checked my Wordpress website after some time and it shows nothing. Could you tell me what's wrong? How can I fix it?

Website: http://coaching.yotta.style

Answer (score 0):

As its showing white page with no error in Console. So Better will be to check website logs from your hosting. Hopefully you will get some clues.

Answer (score 0):

It might there is some PHP error in your site. So, please check the error log or enable error reporting in your server and then check. It might be help full to you.